# Create a new column in SAS with condition

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in SAS, which contains columns SN and RT, I want to create another column which should be with condition that wherever 1 appears 1st in the **RT** list by **SN**  should do 1 and remaining consecutive number 1 to do 0, Please find the example below.

Table1

```
SN  RT
1 0
1 0
1 1
1 1
1 0
2 0
2 0
3 1
3 1
3 1
4 0
4 1
4 1
4 0
```

Output table looks like:

```
 SN  RT Newvar
    1 0    0
    1 0    0
    1 1    1
    1 1    0
    1 0    0
    2 0    0
    2 0    0
    3 1    1
    3 1    0
    3 1    0
    4 0    0
    4 1    1
    4 1    0
    4 0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this problem, Thanks for you answers

```
 data TABLE2 ;
      set TABLE1;
      by SN RT;
      IF first.SN AND first.RT then RETIRE = 1;ELSE RETIRE=0 ;
      WHERE RT=1;
      run;

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE  RETIREMENT(drop=RT)  AS
SELECT T1.* 
,T2.RETIRE
FROM TABLE1  T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2  T2 
ON T1.SN =T2.SN ;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input table (table1) is sorted by SN, the following code should perform the required action:

```
data newtable (drop=_x);
  set table1;
  by SN;
  if first.SN then _x = 1;
  if RT = 1 and _x then do;
    newvar = 1;
    _x = 0;
  end;
  else newvar = 0;
run;
```

When the first value of `SN` is found, a flag `_x` is set to 1, this basically says 'start checking for RT = 1'. When we find the first `RT = 1` we set `newvar = 1` and then reset the `_x` flag so that newvar is only set when the **first** occurrence of `RT = 1` is found within the same `SN` 'group'.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you were looking for. This is not the most elegant of solutions but it should do the trick.

```
DATA given;
    INPUT sn $ rt;
DATALINES;
1 0
1 0
1 1
1 1
1 0
2 0
2 0
3 1
3 1
3 1
4 0
4 1
4 1
4 0
;
RUN;
PROC SORT DATA = given;
    BY sn rt;
RUN; 
DATA new;
    SET given;
    BY sn rt;
        firstrt = first.rt;
        first_occure = rt*firstrt;
    DROP firstrt;
RUN;
PROC PRINT DATA = new;
RUN;
```